# React native Tab implementation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I Have to create a screen in react native  with tabs. There will be 3 tabs at bottom of the screen which i have done. Each screen will have 3 tabs at the top.
Can anyone please tell me hoe to implement the same.

below is  sample screen which im trying to implement[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GYkQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make it your self with a horizontal scrollview. However, in my opinion the best way is to install this component:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 30 }}>
        {/*Example of Tab Indicator*/}
        <IndicatorViewPager
          style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 20, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
          indicator={this._renderTabIndicator()}>
          {/*_renderTabIndicator() will return the PagerTabIndicator*/}
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#C70039',
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 30 }}>One</Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#FF5733',
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 30 }}>Two</Text>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#FFC300',
              flex: 1,
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 30 }}>Three</Text>
          </View>
        </IndicatorViewPager>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _renderTabIndicator() {
    let tabs = [
      {
        text: 'One',
      },
      {
        text: 'Two',
      },
      {
        text: 'Three',
      },
    ];
    return <PagerTabIndicator tabs={tabs} />;
  }
}
```

Above code might help you in achieving what you want.

Comment: thanks for the ans, I'm able to make the tabs following ur  above answer